# Wine: numpad 'dot' key trigger 'dot' and 'delete'

Tags: keyboard, wine, numpad

When I press numpad <kbd>.
Del</kbd> key on a wine, a <kbd>.</kbd> is inserted but <kbd>del</kbd> is also triggered.

I would like only <kbd>.</kbd> key is triggered. how to ?

issue append on any wine software.

I use french keyboard layout. (no append on english layout)

Comment: What app are you having this issue with? I've just checked with `wine notepad`, and it works normally there: I only get `.` inserted, and nothing is deleted after the cursor. Are you sure that you're not in "overwrite" mode (it's usually toggled by the <Insert> button)?

Comment: @Ruslan yes, I have issue on notepad, but I use french keyboard layout. (question edited)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove oss variant.

The problem seems to come from the oss variant in keyboard layout (layout fr). See

```
setxkbmap -query
```

It is solved (for me) by removing this variant:

```
setxkbmap -layout fr
```

For a final modification, edit the file /etc/default/keyboard and delete the line (or comment out) XKBVARIANT="oss"

I hope that the solution will be useful to others while waiting for a next version of wine to be compatible with the oss variant!

taken from here : https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=33839

Comment: Could you expand a little on this answer? As it stands it is not far from being a link only answer, such answers are not encouraged on AU: https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1257977)